# Prevent browser(Chrome) to run default functions like scroll with space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have used two functins here first one for blocking default feature like space bar scroll,etc

```
<span id="current"></span>

$("html").on("keydown", function (e) {
  {
        e.preventDefault();
  }
});
document.onkeypress = function(evt) 
{
     evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=charCode;
};
```

now this code works in firefox for blocking various default functions of firefox like ctrl+a ctrl+s space bar scroll and also gives output in span but when i tried it in chrome ,it also blocks various default functions of chrome but didn't give output in span.

I can also write it as

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) 
{
     evt = evt || window.event;
     var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
     document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=charCode;
     return false;
};
```

It worked for both firfox and chrome
but my function(evt) is very long and contain many if-else loops and if i press double space or press space bar continously then it scrolls down so i want any alternative solution in which i can use two functions one for blocking and other for outputs and it also work in chrome.

Comment: It's usually a frustrating and time consuming process to defeat the built-in features of the browser. People seldom appreciate you disabling parts of the user interface, as well. That's what I've noticed.

Comment: I am create a typing learing website so it needs to block space bar scroll while typing

Comment: Check out the textarea tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: but i have to make it as typing in div

Comment: I think most people focus on the textarea, but then hide it off screen and listen for any changes to give the appearance of typing in a div.

Comment: i can't do it in text area as i have to make a learning website in which each span tag matches with other span tag and then go forward if it is true

Comment: Use the contenteditable attribute instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function (x) {
  {
    x = window.event;
    var cc = evt.keyCode ;
    $('#current').html=cc;
    x.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about combine these two function into one:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (evt) {
  {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=charCode;
  }
});
```